# Virtual Functions during Construction. Why Java is different than C++

Tags: java, c++

I had a test today and one of the questions was about using a virtual method in C++ constructor. I failed this question, I answered that there shouldn't be any problem, however after reading [this](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html) I found out I was wrong.

So I understand that the reason for not allowing that is because the derived object is not fully initialized and therefore calling it's virtual method can cause invalid consequences.

My question how was it solved in Java/C# ? I know that I can call derived method in my base constructor, I would assume that these languages have exactly the same problem.

Comment: Its considered a very *bad idea* to do this in C#; Code Analysis will complain about it, for example. You can try it, but you run the risk of your code doing something unexpected. It's not as severe a problem as it is in C++ for the reasons given in the answers, but you run a very real risk of calling methods on an uninitialized object. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182331.aspx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Java has a very different object model from C++. In Java, you cannot have variables which are objects of class type -- instead, you can only ever have *references* to objects (of class type). Therefore, all members of a class (which are only references) start out trivially as `null` until the entire derived object has been set up in memory. Only then do the constructors run. Thus by the time a base constructor calls a virtual function, even if that function is overridden, the overridden function can at least correctly refer to members of the derived class. (Those members may not themselves be *assigned* yet, but at least they *exist*.)

(If it helps, you can also consider that *every* class without `final` members in Java is technically default-constructible, at least in principle: Unlike in C++, Java has no such things as constants or references (which *must* be initialized in C++), and in fact there are no initializer lists at all. Variables in Java simply don't need to be initialized. They're either primitives which start as 0, or class type references which start as `null`. One exception comes from non-static `final` class members, which cannot be rebound and must actually be "initialized" by having precisely *one* assignment statement somewhere in every constructor [thanks to @josefx for pointing this out!].)

Comment: "There are no such things as constants or references in C++ which must be initialized"
 -- 
This phrasing is a little misleading at first glance.

Comment: @uberwulu: That's true. One of my least proud moments. Do you have a suggestion how to make it clearer? "C++-style constants and references"?

Comment: Hmm, let's see.  Maybe just adding "Unlike C++, in Java" at the beginning could help.

Comment: Haha, nice.  That first shot made me do a double take.  Much clearer now :)

Comment: java still has `final` and these have to be initialized in the ctor.

Comment: @josefx: Thanks - I forgot about that! I added that now.

Answer (score 2):

> understand that the reason for not allowing that is because the derived object is not fully initialized and therefore calling it's virtual method can cause invalid consequences

Wrong. C++ will call the base class's implementation of the method, not the derived class's. There are no 'invalid consequences'. The only valid reason for avoiding the construct is that the behavior sometimes comes as a surprise.

This is *different* from Java because Java calls the derived class's implementation.

Comment: Indeed. There’s no magic or UB happening. The [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/calling-virtuals-from-ctors.html) has a good concise explanation of it.

Answer (score 1):

Every Java constructor looks like this:

```
class Foo extends Bar {
  Foo() {
    super(); // creates Bar
    // do things
  }
}
```

So if you place code working on derived methods in `do things`, seems to be logic, that this base object was initialized properly, after calling its constructor in `super();`

Comment: The code looks odd: 1) "class" is misspelled, 2) `Foo` doesn't seem to inherit from anything, 3) the OP is concerned about virtual functions in the *base* constructor.

Comment: @Kerrek, thanks for suggestions, I've editted 1) and 2). And about 3) - that's why I upvoted your answer :)

Comment: What if Foo overrides method from Bar, and this method is called in Bar constructor? It will be called on non-constructed Foo. My point is that Java is not very far away from C++ in this problem.

Comment: @luskan Very far away. C++ calls the base class's method in this circumstance, not the derived class's.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ every polymorphic class( class that has at least one virtual function ) has a hidden pointer at start of it( usually named v-table or something like that ) that will be initialized to the virtual table( an array of functions that point to the body of each virtual function ) of that class and when you call a virtual function C++ simply call `((v-table*)class)[index of your function]( function-parameters )`, so if you call a virtual function in base class constructor v-table point to virtual table of the base class since your class is base and it still need some initialization to become child and as a result you will call implementation of the function from base not from child and if this is a pure virtual function you will get an access violation.
but in java this is not something like this, in java whole the class is something like `std::map<std::string, JValue>` in this case `JValue` is some variant type( for example a union or `boost::variant` ) when you call a function in constructor of base it will find function name in the map and call it, it is still not the value from the child but you can still call it and if you changed it in the `prototype`, since prototype created before your constructor you can successfully call function from child but if function required some initialization from constructor of the child you still get error or an invalid result.
so in general it is not a good practice to call a function from child( for example a virtual function ) in base class. if your class need to do this add an initialize method and call it from constructor of your child class.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Java/C# avoid this problem by constructing from derived class backwards rather than in C++ from base class forwards.

Java implicitly calls super() in a classes constructor so by the time the first line of written code in a derived class constructor is called all the constructors of all inherited classes are guaranteed to have been called and so the new instance will have been completely initialised.

I think also in C++ a new instance of a class begins life as the base class and gets "upgraded" to the final class type as we move down the inheritance chain.  This means that when you call a virtual function in the constructor you'll actually be calling the version of that function for the base class.

In Java and presumably C# a new instance starts life as the required class type so the correct version of the virtual method will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not entirely avoid the problem.

An overridden method called from a superclass constructor that depends on fields of the subclass will be called before those fields have been initialized.

If you're in control of the entire class hierarchy, you can of course just make sure your overrides don't depend on subclass fields.  But it's safer to just not call virtual methods from constructors.